# Move constrained rigid bodies with empty parent

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

Been stuck on this for a while now, feeling like i'm chasing something that can't happen.
[image: A constrained rigid body not moving as expected]

I read in some posts around that to get a constrained rigid body to move that all one has to do is select it, a passive that its constrained to, and the constraining empty, and then parent them to another empty and animate that one. I've done lots of experimenting and followed many videos to make sure my rigid body system is set up properly but here I am with it not moving at all :(

[image]
[image]
[image]

I really don't know what to do or where to go from here. Anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: Hello could you please describe what kind of animation you want to do exactly?

Comment: There's actually two I'm trying to do. The main one is a nose ring that moved just with the nose as a hinge or point constraint, but I couldn't figure it out. I returned back to basics with the gif above and was able to get the simulation to go on the constraint, but it does not move: https://i.imgur.com/iR3WgMU.gif
Basically I just want a fixed rigid body that simulates as a child of another object

Comment: Passive is for things that never move.  Use dynamic and animated instead.